# Recorrer todas las casillas de un Array string y mostrarlas

Tags: java, array, string, array-bidimensional

Tengo el siguiente array

```
String m1[][]= {{"M01","M02","M03","M04"},{"8","3","9","10"},{"5","8","7","4"},{"10","9","8","9"}};
```

y quiero mostrar la asignatura (M0*) cuya puntuacion sea mayor a 9,como podria hacerlo ? he probado realizando 2 for y luego un if pero no puedo hacer la comparacion en el if porque es string mis datos..

He probado y tengo este codigo el cual me saca los 3 nueve que hay en el Array pero necesito saber a que "M0*" pertenece:

```
for(j=0;j<4;j++) 
            {
                for(int i=0;i<4;i++) 
                {

                    if(m1[i][j].contentEquals("9")) 
                    {
                        System.out.print(" "+m1[i][j]);
                    }


                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si he leído bien, el requerimiento es este:

> ... *y quiero mostrar la asignatura (M0) cuya puntuacion sea mayor a 9, como podria hacerlo ?*

Para hacer esto, dado que los elementos que quieres comparar son cadenas, tendrás que hacer una conversión a entero para luego comparar si son mayores que `9`.

Con esto podrías lograrlo (está todo explicado en los comentarios del código):

```
    String m1[][]= {{"M01","M02","M03","M04"},{"8","3","9","10"},{"5","8","7","4"},{"10","9","8","9"}};
    for (int i = 0; i < m1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m1[i].length; j++) {
            /*Saltamos la 1ª columna*/
            if (i>0){
                /*Convertimos a entero para verificar si es mayor*/
                int thisNumber=Integer.parseInt(m1[i][j]);
                /*Verificamos si es mayor*/
                if (thisNumber >= 9){
                    /*
                        En m1[i][j]  tendremos el valor
                        En m1[0][j]  tendremos la fila de la columna 0
                    */
                    System.out.format("Valor %-5s en %-5s es mayor que 9%n",m1[i][j],m1[0][j]);
                }
            }
        }       
    }
```

**Salida:**

```
Valor 9     en M03   es mayor que 9
Valor 10    en M04   es mayor que 9
Valor 10    en M01   es mayor que 9
Valor 9     en M02   es mayor que 9
Valor 9     en M04   es mayor que 9
```

Comment: Buenas tardes, gracias por su respuesta, he probadosu codigo y la salida es diferente a la mia, solo me muestra 2 asignaturas : un 9 en M03 y un 10 en M01, no me muestra el resto alguna idea del porque ?

Comment: @Anthonyeca la prueba está hecha en base a los valores del objeto `String m1[][]` que hay en tu pregunta. Si no funciona debe ser porque estás usando el código sobre otro objeto o con otros datos.

Comment: Yo lo he hecho igual y no me resulta, no entiendo el porque , he resuelto el problema sin obtener resultados iguales pero obteniendo las Asignaturas cuya nota es 9 o mayor y no se repiten, Muchas gracias, he marcado la suya como correcta igualmente.

Answer (score 0):

He logrado resolverlo con el siguiente codigo :

```
for (j=0;j<m1.length;j++)
        {
            for (int i=0;i<m1.length;i++)
            {
                if(i>0) 
                {
                 int thisNum=Integer.parseInt(m1[i][j]);

                    if(thisNum >= 9)
                    { 
                    System.out.format("Obtuviste un %-5s en %-5s %n",m1[i][j],m1[0][j]);

                    break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Entonces esta debería ser la respuesta marcada como aceptada